# Send email through OTRS API

Tags: web-services, api, otrs

I currently have the below that updates an OTRS ticket using by calling the link /otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket

It works great, but how can I get it to send an email to the customer when the ticket is updated as well?

```
var body = JSON.stringify ({
    "Ticket":{
        "StateID":params.state},
        "Article":{
            "ArticleTypeID":params.noteType,
            "Subject":params.subject,
            "Body":params.bodyText,
            "ContentType":params.contentType
        }
    }
);

//Build the full URL for our webservice query.
var LoginURL = authenticate.URL + "/" +
TicketID +
"?UserLogin=" + authenticate.UserLogin +
"&Password=" + authenticate.Password;

//Perform the actual work. As well as the URL of the webservoce
var client = new apiclient.ApiClient({ serverid: this.serverid });
var resp = client.invoke( "formutils", "httpRequest", {
    "url": LoginURL,
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": { 
    "ContentType":"application/json"},
    "body": body
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you update a ticket via the web service API, by default this will NOT trigger sending an email to the customer, not even if you set the article type as 'email-external'.

If you do want this to happen, the best way is to create a new Notification (prior to OTRS 5 this would be an 'Event Based Notification') as described here: http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/administration.html#adminarea-ticket-notifications

You can match on the ArticleCreate event, the user who created the ticket via the Web Service, and maybe other attributes as well.

https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/6c87d2b1370b917629a99df7e080b8f87f051581/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketUpdate.pm#L1936 calls the internal API `ArticleCreate()` which never sends email whereas `ArticleSend()` does.

There is an extension published by Znuny which you could install on your OTRS system that exposes this functionality to the web service as well: https://github.com/znuny/Znuny4OTRS-GIArticleSend

Comment: I'm not creating a ticket with this.  I'm updating a ticket, so the ticket itself already exists.  Is there something else that needs to be set to trigger the email?

Comment: You're right - I did not pay close enough attention. But it's still a similar problem, the web service for ticket updates calls the internal API  `ArticleCreate()` where you would need `ArticleSend()` for sending out mails to customers.